# Visual Studio interface issue on Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio, user-interface, interface, refresh

I've been trying to install Visual Studio on my machine running Windows 10, however there seems to be a weird issue with both Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2013 (Community edition).

The problem seems to be that the user interface doesn't get rendered/updated properly. I have uploaded a video demonstrating the issue [here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w4FolUwTOjQ) If I click on any item in the list on the left, it doesn't show that it's selected. The preview image on the right seems to update, but it doesn't get cleared so the images are overlapping.

Has anyone else experienced this problem or know how to solve this?
I am running Windows 10 Home, 64-bit edition.

Comment: Your video is private

Comment: Oops, my bad. Shouldn't be private anymore.

Comment: Update your video card drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably is a problem with your graphics card driver.
As workaround, try to use sofware rendering as specified in Microsoft KB:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2894215

Comment: This fixed my problem. Thanks for the help!!